# SharePoint Labels Reliably Updating

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, label, sharepoint-2007

In a MOSS 2007 / Office 2007 environment I am having spotty results with SharePoint properties updating in a Word document. Using an Information Management Policy, I define a Label Format:

```
Version: {Version}\n Effective Date: {MyModifiedDate}
```

I add a label to the footer of the Content Type template.

When I create a document based on my configured Content Type, check it in and then look at the document, the footer doesn’t always update. This is especially true the first time I check the document in.

If I just use Version the label updates as expected, but when I use other properties the results are inconsistent.

Everything I read makes it sound simple, but in our case it is unreliable, therefore not production ready. Do you have any experience with this would share or could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have the same problem in SP2013. When I put the version only, it works fine but if I use other fields, the {Version} içsn't correctly replaced by the number.